# Jquery and Jslint - '$' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I have some third party javascript im working with, I added some jquery  code into it the javascript file. But it seems to fail on the above code when validating using Jslint

```
'$' was used before it was defined.
```

I can see at the top of the javascript file it states:

```
/*global alert: false, console: false, jQuery: false */
```

Im relatively new to Javascript, and JQuery, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: `Above code`? Did you forget to add it for us to see?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Add these options to your comments:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
```

Comment: Documentation on this is here under the "Global Variables" section: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Comment: Why is it like that? Why can't JSLint just know JQuery?

Comment: Because there is a world without jQuery, for example on Node.js or on Java Rhino. You don't always want jQuery in your environments, otherwise it could be build into the VM :-P

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use variables provided by other scripts, then you need to say so:

```
/*global $ */
```

Answer (score 2):

For **JSLint In Netbeans** IDE go to:

`Tools` - `Options` - `Miscellaneous` - `JSLint tab` - `Text area` under "*Predefined (, separated)*":

- add $;
- add your other project global variables, separating with comma.

Now JQuery variable $ is considered defined everywhere in code.