# "$ was used before it was defined" error. How to get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I'm trying to use in Brackets in my JS-file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input").focusin(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#D9D9D2");
});
$("input").focusout(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
});
```

});

This should work fine, I guess. I'm trying to get my input-fields a different color when someone focus. Brackets doesn't want to execute this code, because it says '$ is used before it was defined'

I tried executing this code with the errors, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you link to jQuery in your html file?

Comment: Yes, I did. The script-tag is correct and the files are all in the same directory.  did remove the script-tag though out of the header and placed it near the end-tag of the body, because otherwise some ID-getters couldn't find elements I'm looking for.

Comment: not working in browser for different reasons you haven't closed all braces. Use proper indenting and you will see it

Comment: That's because you copied only what's in the code-section of my post. The last two brackets are strangely outside the code-section. In my program, it says it expected ''use strict"; and $ isn't defined when $ is used

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting all input using

```
$(":input")
```

If you're trying to select all input. (Source: [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/))

Otherwise, select the element by id,

```
$("#textInput")
```

Or by input type

```
$("input [type='text']")
```

Hopefully that fixes your problem.

Also, by any chance are you using Jslint?

If so, this sometimes causes problems as mentioned here:

[Jquery and Jslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251388/jquery-and-jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined)

The second answer may even fix your problem if you don't use jslint:

> If you want to use variables provided by other scripts, then you need to say so:

```
/*global $ */
```

Comment: Thanks! It did fix my problem, I don't get any errors by Jslint, but it doesn't work somehow.

Comment: Yes, it helped to get rid of the errors Jslint is giving me. But..the code doesn't do what it should do. It didn't effect my html-page at all. The fields are still the same colour.

Comment: Did you click the link and try the first answer?

Comment: Also, in what order did you link to jquery, your scripts, etc? Peerhaps you are linking them to your page in an order that is causing this